# What Kendo UI controls are not responsive (UX)?

Tags: kendo-ui

I heard that not all controls from Kendo UI are responsive (by design).  I tried searching through documentation and I am unable to find any clue.  I would like to know if there is really a case as such.

Especially, I would like to know if anyone had any "responsive" problems with "Kendo UI Window"

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive" problems with "Kendo UI Window" ?

Comment: The "Kendo UI Window" may not be resizing/rendering correctly on smart devices (like tablets or smartphones)